# Compile On Save with Angular 6 and VS 2017

Tags: angular, visual-studio

I have followed this sample. And it got me going with a new Angular project in VS 2017. However when I do changes in app.component.html and refresh the browser the changes are note reflected. I tried setting "compileOnSave": true in the ts.config file, and disabling cache in browser with no luck. Its kind of strange that it runs the fist time i run the applications, but changes are just not reflected. Is something missing in the article?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue should be because of the files in dist folder. Try deleting them and recompile your app. Should be working.